# Objective-C How to play videos on MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer instantly, without delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I have tried playing 500 KB videos on AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController, and they both have a slightly annoying delay. AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController both display a black screen for 2-3 seconds, and then it starts the video. Thats really annoying, how come it takes so long for the video to start? How can I fix it?

```
 //Movie Player Code
_moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:video];
    _moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    _moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    _moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    _moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.frame;
    [_moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    _moviePlayerVC.view.frame = self.frame;

    [self addSubview:_moviePlayerVC.view];

//AVPlayer Code
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:video];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
    _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
    layer.frame = self.frame;
    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    [layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

Comment: Tried your AVPlayer code but nothing ever appeared on the screen. Is there an addsubview or similar statement missing from your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could preload an `AVPlayer` and observe its `status`. Once it changes `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` you should be able to start playback without any delay.

Comment: it doesnt work still, there is still a delay for some reason. Like the audio even starts before the video is displayed. PS what do you mean by preload an AVPlayer.